# Edit Composed key in AspNetUserRoles Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am using MCV5 with ASP Identity and made some modification in table AspNetUserRole:

```
public class AspNetUserRole : IdentityUserRole
{
    [key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

because I need to add Id key column and integrate it to composite key (UserId and RoleId) to become like that (UserId,RoleId and Id)

Code for onModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.Id , r.RoleId, r.UserId});
         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

but I have Id as a normal string column in database without any primary key constrains